# .sh File Not Found

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sh

I'm trying to execute test.sh on terminal.

My test.sh is in the /Home/monty folder and I made it executable:

```
chmod 755 test.sh
```

I try to execute it using:
    $./test.sh
I get an error:

```
bash: ./test.sh: /usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I tried to do this on terminal:

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/Home/monty
```

But to no avail. 
How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Is test.sh executable (permissions)?

Comment: You *may* also need to do `export PATH=$PATH:/Home/monty`. Depending on whether PATH is already exported (though it probably is).

Comment: Yes, it is @TomDalton. I just edited the question. Seemingly, it had nothing to do with execvp() or python.

Comment: does  /usr/bin/bash exist?

Comment: Ahh. What os are you using? What do you get if you run `which bash`?

Comment: Assuming your default shell is bash, you're probably safest to use `#!/bin/sh` in your shell script[s].

Comment: I get `/bin/bash` @TomDalton

Comment: @Zac /usr/bin/bash does not exist

Comment: in another case, `-sh: /etc/init.d/me.sh: not found` or `...bad interpreter: No such file or directory` or similar will be shown if your script file has Windows-style line endings.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You probably have set the wrong shabang. In ubuntu bash is normally located in `/bin/bash` so at the top of the file you should have:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

instead of:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

---

Another way to run the script is to just tell `bash` (or `sh`) to execute it:

```
bash ./test.sh
```

Comment: Using `bash` did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

I solved the problem by changing the end of the line from CRLF to LF since my script was edited in windows.

Comment: how did you do that

Comment: You can do it (in Windows) in Notepad++ Edit->EOL Conversion->Unix (LF)

Comment: This probably saved me from hours of frustration. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I did `sh file.sh`, which was definately there, but in the file I had `cp /other/file.sh` and the other file was missing. Yet the error message only said `sh file.sh: Not found`.